# TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an error in my use of AJAX:

> TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement....plete",[C,p]),--x.active||x.event.trigger("ajaxStop")))}return C},getJSON:functi...

Here is the parts of my code where I use it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

It is my javascript code that works on checkboxes where I defined them before:

```
function feedback() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
        if (boxes[j].checked) {
            //assign(1);
            assign = 1;
        } else {
            assign = 0;
            //assign(0);
        }
        var wordid = document.getElementsByClassName('wordId')[j];
        $.ajax({
            url: "assigner.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                wordid: wordid,
                assign: assign
            }
        }).done(function(e) {
            /*alert( "word was saved" + e );*/
        });
    }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work and it doesn't give me any errors.

```
var newvalue = '';
$('input[name=wordid\\[\\]]').each(function(index, element) {
    newvalue = newvalue + this.value + ',';
});
$.ajax({
    url: "assigner.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        wordid: newvalue,
        assign: assign
    }
}).done(function(e) {
    /*alert( "word was saved" + e );*/
});
```

Answer (score 84):

`$.ajax` is not expecting a DOMElement of type `HTMLInputElement` in the object you are passing to `data`. Try just giving it the value of the field instead:

```
var wordid = $('.wordId').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "assigner.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { wordid: wordid, assign: assign}
}).done(function( e ) {
    /*alert( "word was saved" + e );*/
});
```

Comment: wordId is name of a array of checkboxes, I want to send each of them to assigner.php
what can I do?
     
      echo "<input class ='wordId' type='hidden' \>";

Comment: Great solution. It solved my question by just reading first few words of first line ;)

Comment: @Rory: you are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the checkbox values like following.

```
var newvalue='';
$('input[name=wordid\\[\\]]').each(function(index, element) {
                        newvalue=newvalue+this.value+',';
                    });
```

Then pass the value of variable 'newvalue' to the assign.php file. Hope this may help you.

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't work, I put my code above.

Comment: did you define the name of checkboxes as wordid[]

Comment: this way send the first word to assigner.php and set wordid=0 always
I want to send all of the words

Comment: okay.. i got you.. Please define the name of text-box as wordid[] not as wordid[0], wordid[1].. by using above code you will get a string in 'newvalue' with all the values of wordid separated with comma. you can split this string using explode() in assigner.php.

Comment: <input name='wordId[]' value="somevalue" type='hidden' \> put the input field like this. Same name for all, values are different.