# How to pass a spring form as an argument to ajax call through javascript function?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have a Spring Form which has two buttons in JSP file.

```
<input type="button" onclick="saveTopicsActions(this.form)" class="btn primary publish border16" id="saveBtn" value="Save"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn primary publish border16" id="publishBtn" value="Publish"/>
```

The onClick() function of Save button should take this form as an argument and pass the same to an Ajax Call.

```
function saveTopicsActions(form){
            jsonData={};
            jsonData = form;
            VR.appendToJSObject(jsonData);
            var jqxhr = $.post(saveTopicsActionsURL, jsonData, function(returnString) {
                if (returnString == 'true'){
                    showAutoSaveMessage();
                }else{
                    alert(returnString);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
            jqxhr.error(function(data){
                //This one is highly unlikely
                alert("There was a problem  - please contact support");
                window.location.reload();
            });
```

But, This is throwing below the javascript exception

[TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bor7a.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536963/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlin)

Answer (score 0):

don't send a form it is DOM element, try sending the values in ajax, form a JSONobject and send as parama in the AJAX call.

[TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536963/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlin)

go through the above link once

Comment: I'm not sure if I can send all the form element's values to function and then prepare JSON, coz if I click on Save button it should save all the values to the database. Any Idea of how to do it would be very helpful.

Comment: don't send values to function on click, use form id and read all the values and form a json object and the fire the ajax call