# array push() jQuery got TypeError: 'stepUp'

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got

**TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.**

in this code

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".save",function(){
      var message = "";
      var many = [];
      var id = jQuery("#id");
      jQuery(".list .beName").each(function(e){
        var row = e + 1;
        var bname = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val());
        if (bname == "") {
          message += "Please input name in row "+row+"\n";
        }
      });
      if (message != ""){
        alert(message);
        return false;
      }else{
        jQuery(".list .bename").each(function(){
            var bname = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val());
            if(bname != ""){
              many.push(bname);
              jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ben_add.php",
                data:{
                  "id" : id,
                  "beName" : many,
                  "save" : true
                }
              });
            }
        });
      } 
 });
```

what i want is to get the **value/array/data** of **many.push(bname);** and send it into **jQuery.ajax**

**.list** is the *class* of `<li>`

**.bename** is the *class* of `<input>`

**bename** is the *name* of `<input>`

other details here is my **HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
    <li class="list" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><input type="text" class="beName" name="beName"><a href="#" class="remove">x</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="save" name="save">Save</a>
```

my **html** was **append();**

Comment: I'm a little confused, is `stepUp` a function that you've created?

Comment: remove " ",  try `id : id` , `bName : many`  like this

Comment: @HectorLorenzo no sir its kind of error

Comment: Right now your code sends request for each input. It seems you need to move `jQuery.ajax` part away from `.each` loop.

Comment: @ihemant360 i still got stepUp error

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i still got stepUp i put my ajax outside of else

Comment: @reyjoel I didn't say it would fix your error. I have just noticed that you are sending multiple requests.

Comment: change `dataType: "script"` and try

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ahh thank you sir. So the flow of my code is now correct sir/maam? bdw what make it a stepUp error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536963/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies on this line,

`var id = jQuery("#id");`

*The error occurs when you try to pass a jQuery object in ajax call. Ajax params expect a value and not `DOMElement` or `HTMLInputElement`*.

Use `.val()` or `text()` according to your need.

Comment: if i want one id but many bename which of this i should use? **var id = jQuery("#id").text();** or **var id = jQuery("#id").val();**

Comment: What is `#id`? you need to show your html. If it is `<input>` use `.val()` else `text()`. And the passing of many/one `bename` does not depend on this.

Comment: i think the wrong is in my **html** cause i didnt specify its id

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference. Its really a confussing message (stepup ... HTMLInputElement.) Just check variables passed to ajax, get or post. For example, output all of them to console. Maybe one of the variables is not properly initialized,

```
{

  action: 'find_sentences',
  nonce: namespace.nonce,
  find:  JSON.stringify({ data: this.source_array}),
  source_language: this.source_language,
  target_language: this.target_language,

}
```