# jQuery $.post - TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to send a post request:

```
$.post("profile/changepassword",

    {
        "currPass": $currPass,
        "newPass": $newPass,
        "confNewPass": $confNewPass
    }

).always(function(data, status, error) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);

});
```

When I execute this code I get in console:

```
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement. 
[jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:71314]
```

What I get that TypeError?

Comment: Maybe this link help you ,Look at this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536963/typeerror-stepup-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlin?rq=1

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi Yes. The problem was at `data`. I sent fields value like `$currPass`(reference to input) instead of `$currPass.val()`;